# Changing [(ngModel)] binding programmatically from controller

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to update the value of an ngModel from within the controller without actually editing the value inside a textarea

```
<textarea [(ngModel)]="settings.value" #textarea
          style="display: none;"></textarea>

<button (click)="openEditorDialog(settings.value, textarea)">
    Edit Code
</button>
```

Mind that I am not using the `ReactiveFormsModule` but the regular `FormsModule` in this case. Using the Reactive module is not an option in this scenario as the inputs are generated dynamically after fetching the "blueprint" from the server

**controller**

```
openEditorDialog(code: string, textarea: HTMLTextAreaElement): void {

    ...
    // updating code through a dialog
    // `updateCode` has the updated value correctly stored
    ...
    // Trying to update the textarea's value in hope the binding would
    // update for `settings.value` as well
    textarea.value = updateCode

    // tried with `cdr.detectChanges()` without success
}
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/H1vE38gUwlPP35GQOjaJ?p=preview)

**UPDATE**
If I remove the `display: none` property from the textarea, I can see that the content of the `textarea` element has changed, but the the property `settings.value` it self has not been updated.

Comment: `ngModel` is two way binding.. you just have to set data to`settings.value`..

Comment: @suraj it is if you "just have to set data" in the template, but this case is different. please read through and test it out your self

Comment: Just assign the new value to `settings.value`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I accidentally upvoted your comment, no it won't work, please see my plunker for details

Comment: I'm not able to see what the problem is.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer please assume that you do not have access to settings.value from the controller as I said, the form is generated dynamically by looping through an array of input types (e.g text, html, boolean). When the type is HTML, I want to open a dialog that has an HTML editor in it, I then want to assign the value from the editor to `settings.value` through my component. If you open my plunker and read the comment carefully you will understand what I mean. Please don't assume this is a basic 2 way binding question, I have used Angular 2 since it's early beta

Comment: If you open my plunker and click on "Update Value" button, you can see that the content of the `<textarea>` has changed, but if you open your console, you notice that the value of `settings.value` inside the component has not changed

Comment: It would be helpful to see this code that generates the input. I don't see why it wouldn't be possible to access `settings.value` from anywhere. You can always provide access using a shared service.

Comment: "you notice that the value of settings.value inside the component has not changed", that's because that's not supposed to work. You can fire a `change` event on the text area to get `ngModel` take up the change, but that seems quite similar to me like hitting your thumb with a hammer.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I updated my plunker with the input simulated. Note that you aren't allowed to change the value by actually typing directly in the `textarea`, you have to change the value inside the component.

Comment: So, what's the problem with finding the first element in `settingsConfig` that matches `settings.type` and update it's `value` property.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer there's no problem with that, that is the method I currently use to overcome this issue. I was just asking if there is a better solution to handle this situation.

Comment: No, this is how you do it in Angular2+. You manipulate the model and use directives to update the DOM to reflect the model. Try to avoid to meddle with the DOM directly from your code.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thanks. After some more browsing and researching I found a couple of your answers with similar cases, in particular to triggering the 'click' event on a file input. I came to my answer based on yours on other questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some fiddling and reading through the source code, I found out that we can manually trigger the update event on the `textarea` to make Angular pick up the changes

```
openEditorDialog(code: string, textarea: HTMLTextAreaElement): void {

    // do stuff with code, assume it is now stored in `updateCode`
    ...

    textarea.value = updateCode

    // triggering the input event will make Angular pick up the changes
    // made to the textarea by setting it's value
    textarea.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'))
}
```